# code for capture pointcloud from kinect doesn't work

Tags: c++, kinect, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I tried the code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926060/pcl-create-a-pcd-cloud), the second one, but it doesn't work.
Actually, during the execution I try to push 's' button but it doesn't save anything. I tried also to use breakpoints in debug mode, but never change the value of the variable char c.
What happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved in the following manner. I substituted this code:

```
std::string c;
std::getline (std::cin,c); 
std::string str2 ("s\n");
if( str2.compare(c)) {//as before}
```

to that provided:

```
c = getchar(); 
if( c == 's' ){}
```

With my solution it works well!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested your sensor? You can download for example [NiTE](http://www.openni.org/files/nite/) and run:

```
cd NiTE/Samples/Bin
./UserViewer
```

Comment: My kinect works well. I can see the viewer and the streaming. What doesn't work is the saving files pushing 's' key on my keyboard

Comment: Nothing else suggestions?