# How do I store libfreenect data in a point cloud?

Tags: c++, c++11, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, openkinect

How do I store the data from the kinect v1 into an xyzrgb cloud on Linux?  I have already written the pcl portion of my project that involves the kinect and just have to write the part from the kinect that opens a stream and returns data for the point cloud.  I have searched high and low but cannot find a comprehensive answer.

Comment: You should specify which Kinnect and which operating system your using (ie windows, linux, mac, etc). Kinect v1 (XBOX 360 version) has fairly well working drivers for all major OS but the v2 (XBOX One version) has support for windows but only experimental drivers for linux.   Also it's not just a simple as opening a stream to the data. You'll need to register the depth image to the color image to produce a XYZRGB point cloud.

Comment: @TimothyMurphy It is now edited

Comment: I'm a little busy right now to give a full answer. Try looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926060/pcl-create-a-pcd-cloud. Personally I use ROS (robot operating system) to handle capturing the point cloud data (but i'm also using it with a turtlebot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [OKPCL by Qworg on github](https://github.com/Qworg/OKPCL)